# JSR validations not working with custom validator spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a simple spring boot REST application. here is how the DTO looks like:

```
@Data
public class FooDto {
@Min(value = 0L)
@NotNull
private final String amount;

@ValidTimestamp
private final String timestamp;
}
```

I have some validation logic present in `@ValidTimestamp` checking timestamp format is valid or not. but the issue is, the moement i put `@ValidTimestamp` annotation here, all other default JSR validations in the whole DTO stop working. They dont fire up at all. If i comment out `@ValidTimestamp` then those default JSR validations become active. I have looked up all over internet but could not find any solution. Appreciate quick pointers.

Here is the validator class:

```
public class TimestampValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidTimestamp, String> {

@Override
public void initialize(@NonNull final ValidTimestamp constraintAnnotation) {
    constraintAnnotation.payload();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(final String timestamp,
                       @NonNull final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    try {

        final Duration duration = Duration.between(Instant.parse(timestamp), Instant.now());
        throwIfOldTimeStampProvided(duration);
        throwIfFutureTimestampProvided(duration);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dateTimeParseException) {
        return throwInvalidTimestampFormatException(dateTimeParseException);
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean throwInvalidTimestampFormatException(@NonNull final DateTimeParseException dateTimeParseException) {
    log.error("failed to parse the timestamp, exception is : {}", dateTimeParseException);
    throw new InvalidTimestampFormatException("invalid timestamp supplied via request");
}

private void throwIfOldTimeStampProvided(@NonNull final Duration duration) {
    if (duration.toMillis() > ACTIVE_TRANSACTION_TIME_REFERENCE * 1000) {
        throw new StaleTransactionException("Transaction time is  more than a minute ago");
    }
}

private void throwIfFutureTimestampProvided(@NonNull final Duration duration) {
    if (duration.isNegative()) {
        throw new FutureTransactionException("Transaction time is of future");
    }
}
}
```

And here is the annotation:

```
@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {TimestampValidator.class})
public @interface ValidTimestamp {
    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the annotation `@ValidTimestamp` ?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni: added more details. thanks

Comment: A validator is not supposed to throw an exception. Not sure that's what it does, but I guess so, based on the name of your methods. Post all the relevant code.

Comment: @JBNizet: In principle, i agree, it is not supposed to throw exceptions, but i had specific use case for it. Nevertheless, it should not impact the issue at hand anyways. i have updated the rest of section of code as well. hope it helps now.

Comment: It does: since your validator throws instead of returning false, the other validators are not called anymore: you have prevented them from executing by throwing an exception rather than returning an expected result.

Comment: @JBNizet: I see. that may be cause. let me try to remove them and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet: i figured that was the cause. I should have seen that coming :), my bad.